# Top bar auto-update

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Is it possible to get the top-bar of SU to auto-update it's values without having to refresh the page?  The inbox new message count indicator is the one I want mainly, although rep would be nice too ;)

Maybe also have it fixed at the top of the screen so it's always there while you're scrolling through answers, or writing an answer, so you know if you've got messages / notifications waiting while you're writing.

Comment: I see you're gaining far too much rep, the bar can't keep up with you!

Comment: heh... It's more for the inbox than the rep that I'd find it useful @IvoFlipse

Comment: The [Multicollider/GlobalInbox now auto updates][1] with your notifications.


  [1]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125677/133693

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [this stackapps userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/1703/so-live-live-updates-to-your-reputation-score) which keeps your rep fairly up to date.

Change the function linkify() to

```
function linkify(change){
    // see chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/479425#479425
    dummy = $("<hack/>")
    what_I_want = $("<a/>").text(change.title)
                           .attr("href", "http://" + so_live_site + "/q/" + change.post_id + "/-1")
    dummy.append(what_I_want)
    return dummy[0].innerHTML
  }
```

Comment: Nice, (so nice I have installed it) but it doesn't update the inbox unread count.  Is there a userscript for that?

Comment: Actually - that script doesn't work well in GreaseMonkey - *+10 reputation for undefined*

Comment: @MattJenkins: The Author has fixed it and an update should be available soon but the 'fix' is in my post.

Comment: Cool.  Fix applied.  Not sure if it's working yet - hit the rep cap for the day.

Comment: @MattJenkins: change `so_live_site` to `site` too :(.